Consolidate String or Array Value
Have a got list of string "ABC,ABC,XYZ,DEF,ABC,DEF". Is there a way to consolidate the common string values and output as one? Hence output "ABC,XYZ,DEF,".
Same for arrarys. Is there a way to consolidate the common values?
["ABC,ABC,XYZ,DEF,ABC,DEF"]

Use the advanced data operations connector and the distinct operation.

@Skin could you please showcase with the above example.

You can use an union function in an expression for this.
Below is an example
union(variables('varArray'),variables('varArray'))


This would be the result

